# Random Word API Usage

Tags: javascript, html, random

I'm trying to use the random word api from setsetgo.

So I build this html to test it out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
    function RandomWord() {
        var requestStr = "http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: requestStr,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: 'RandomWordComplete'
        });

    }


    function RandomWordComplete(data) {
        alert(data.Word);
    }

    RandomWord();
    RandomWordComplete(data);
</script> 
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like the script stop when I do $.ajax() . Though, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In your second function call where do you think the variable data came from and what would it have inside of it?

Comment: you're not including the jquery script

Comment: Check the developer console (F12) for errors.

Comment: I tried with the jquery script and it's still not working. I thought the data var comes from $.ajax

Comment: It would, but not at that scope - only inside the callback would it be available. You are calling `RandomWordComplete(data);` explicitly before the ajax call has time to complete so even if you _could_ access `data` it would not have values yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function RandomWord() {
    var requestStr = "http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: requestStr,
        dataType: "jsonp",
    }).done(RandomWordComplete);
}

function RandomWordComplete(data) {
    alert(data.Word);
}

RandomWord();
```

Comment: I don't know the randomword site, but they say you have to register an id: see http://randomword.setgetgo.com/

Comment: The website is actually http://setgetgo.com/randomword/  for the random word generator and it has its id already (it was built on top of setgetgo)